VS code isn't focused when I click on it on my Ubuntu machine
Whenever I click on vs code with my mouse, It focuses on the window behind or other apps. I am using Ubuntu 24.04. I don't know if this has any relation with it since it worked fine on older versions.
I tried reinstalling vs code with different methods (snap package, deb. package) but all of them have the same problem. Keep in mind that each time I reinstalled it, I also removed the dependencies from the system and removed the ./Config/code directory and the .vscode file from the home directory on my machine.

Welcome! Please copy and paste the output of the Help: About command (run in the command palette) into your question post.

I have a similar issue with Microsoft Edge and any non-native application. I have to click the top bar, and then the application reduces its size on the screen. Then, I can either close the app or access some of its menus. I have Ubuntu 22.04, and I do not have this issue. It only applies to 24.04.

i run on terminal "code --verbose" end got vulkan problem:
Warning: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_lvp.so: classe ELF errada: ELFCLASS32
Warning: loader_icd_scan: Failed loading library associated with ICD JSON /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_lvp.so. Ignoring this JSON
Warning: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_intel.so: classe ELF errada: ELFCLASS32
Warning: loader_icd_scan: Failed loading library associated with ICD JSON /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_intel.so. Ignoring this JSON
Warning: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_virtio.so: classe ELF errada: ELFCLASS32
Warning: loader_icd_scan: Failed loading library associated with ICD JSON /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_virtio.so. Ignoring this JSON
Warning: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_radeon.so: classe ELF errada: ELFCLASS32
Warning: loader_icd_scan: Failed loading library associated with ICD JSON /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_radeon.so. Ignoring this JSON
Warning: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_intel_hasvk.so: classe ELF errada: ELFCLASS32
Soh i start ubuntu in Xorg mode.

so did Xorg mode "fix" the issue?

Try running this command in terminal:
pkill -HUP mutter-x11-frames

